# How to add servicePointManager to web config in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to add the following lines to web config

```
 <system.net>
  <settings>
      <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false" />
  </settings>
```

But it returning error Only one  element allowed. It must be the first child element of the root  element

Can any one please help on us?

Answer (score 2):

```
   try this in webconfig or refer MSDN for details
 <configuration>
     <system.net>
       <settings>
         <servicePointManager
            checkCertificateName="false"
            checkCertificateRevocationList="false"         
         />
      </settings>
    </system.net>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: then please search in msdn.It may contain detailed explanation.